# JavaMail OAuth AuthenticationFailed Exception

Tags: oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, google-oauth

I'm trying to connect to gmail server via javamail and trying to authenticate via OAuth.

Here is the code which does that.

```
public static void connect() {

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true"); //required for Gmail
    props.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com",  993, "abcimap@gmail.com", "ya29.Glx2BW9zm7wSsr9WV66KhC4kZa7dbrOA9P6HT3EMwmiLbmkdjbHZM5oHi8VfHhxM-VNDntRxQBZ_GzMM2rMa1cAxnQ3GiNaR_M9SRfT9sCIXe0l4Rz_mNM8a40aqZw");


    Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    IMAPFolder imapFolder = (IMAPFolder)folder;
}
```

But I get,

> Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
>       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:715)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)

A related question here : [Problems with JavaMail, GMail and OAUTH2 (not Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704510/problems-with-javamail-gmail-and-oauth2-not-android/49131045)

asks to set scope. But I'm not sure where to set it. Whether it is in the java code or outside it.

Can you please help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The scope is set when you create the access token.

Here's the shell script I used to generate the OAuth2 token, along with instructions:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Go to this URL in a browser:
# https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://mail.google.com/&redir
ect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&client_id=793...42.apps.googleusercontent.com
# it will display a confirmation page.  once confirmed it will redirect
# to something like this, which will fail in the browser:
# http://localhost/?code=4/0g...
# copy the code from the failed URL and use the code below

curl \
        --data-urlencode client_id=793...42
.apps.googleusercontent.com \
        --data-urlencode client_secret=<my-secret> \
        --data-urlencode 'code=4/0g...' \
        --data-urlencode redirect_uri=http://localhost \
        --data-urlencode grant_type=authorization_code \
        https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

Obviously you'll need to replace the client_id and secret with your values.